# Troubles setting up Capybara / Selenium tests in Github Actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara, github-actions

I am setting up a Github Actions workflow to run the entire test suite of a rails webapp and have some troubles with tests that use Capybara and Selenium (and sadly I have close to no experience with those tools!).

Here is the error message from Github Actions:

```
22) Participant authentication Participant signs out
      Failure/Error: visit '/'

      Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
        Reached error page: about:neterror?e=dnsNotFound&u=http%3A//project.example.com%3A31337/&c=UTF-8&d=We%20can%E2%80%99t%20connect%20to%20the%20server%20at%20project.example.com.
      # WebDriverError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:181:5
      # UnknownError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:488:5
      # checkReadyState@chrome://marionette/content/navigate.js:63:24
      # onNavigation@chrome://marionette/content/navigate.js:317:39
      # emit@resource://gre/modules/EventEmitter.jsm:160:20
      # receiveMessage@chrome://marionette/content/actors/MarionetteEventsParent.jsm:40:25
      # ./spec/features/public/registration_and_authentication_spec.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
```

Here is the worklflow yml file:

```
name: Continuous Integration
on:
  push:
    branches: [ setup-github-actions-2 ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ setup-github-actions-2 ]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:11
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
        options: --health-cmd pg_isready --health-interval 10s --health-timeout 5s --health-retries 5
    steps:
      - name: Set Timezone
        run: |
          sudo timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Paris

      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup chrome driver (for Selenium)
        uses: nanasess/setup-chromedriver@master
        # with:
          # Optional: do not specify to match Chrome's version
          # chromedriver-version: '88.0.4324.96'
      - run: |
          export DISPLAY=:99
          chromedriver --url-base=/wd/hub &
          sudo Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x24 > /dev/null 2>&1 & # optional

      - uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: 2.7.2
          bundler-cache: true # runs 'bundle install' and caches installed gems automatically

      - name: Install node modules
        uses: borales/actions-yarn@v2.0.0
        with:
          cmd: install

      - name: Install dependent libraries
        run: sudo apt-get install libpq-dev

      - name: Bundle install
        run: |
          gem install bundler
          bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 3

      - name: Setup Database
        run: |
          cp config/database.yml.example config/database.yml
          bundle exec rake db:create
          bundle exec rake db:schema:load
        env:
          RAILS_ENV: test
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

      - name: Run RSpec on helpers
        if: always() # make sure to not stop the workflow if one test fails
        run: bundle exec rspec spec/helpers
        env:
          RAILS_ENV: test
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

      - name: Run RSpec on jobs
        if: always()
        run: bundle exec rspec spec/jobs
        env:
          RAILS_ENV: test
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

      - name: Run RSpec on lib
        if: always()
        run: bundle exec rspec spec/lib
        env:
          RAILS_ENV: test
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

      - name: Run RSpec on mailers
        if: always()
        run: bundle exec rspec spec/mailers
        env:
          RAILS_ENV: test
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

      - name: Run RSpec on models
        if: always()
        run: bundle exec rspec spec/models
        env:
          RAILS_ENV: test
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

      - name: Run RSpec on controllers
        if: always()
        run: bundle exec rspec spec/controllers
        env:
          RAILS_ENV: test
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

      - name: Run RSpec on requests
        if: always()
        run: bundle exec rspec spec/requests
        env:
          RAILS_ENV: test
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

      # 28 examples, 25 failures => Selenium error
      - name: Run RSpec on features
        if: always()
        run: bundle exec rspec spec/features
        env:
          RAILS_ENV: test
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

      - name: Run Jest test suite
        if: always()
        run: bundle exec yarn test
        env:
          RAILS_ENV: test
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```

To be noted that the tests work fine locally.

Any clue on what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, here is what I was missing to have my tests pass with my specific configuration:

```
steps:
    - name: Add hosts to /etc/hosts
      run: |
        sudo echo "172.16.18.16 example.test" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
        sudo echo "172.16.18.16 example2.test" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

Reference: https://github.community/t/add-host-to-etc-hosts/17364

Answer (score 1):

From the error message you can see that the browser is being sent to `http://project.example.com/...` which doesn't exist, and even if it did wouldn't be where your test app is running. Assuming you're running the same test config locally, it's possible you have `project.example.com` pointed at localhost/127.0.0.1 (check your /etc/hosts or local DNS configuration) which would make your tests work there.  You need to update your test configuration so tests run against whichever ip your app under test is being run on.